# Ext GWT. Column event not working.

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

When i add listener `column.addListener(Events.CellClick, new Listener<BaseEvent>()` it doesnt work on column. But if I add listener to Grid. then its works. How to fire event when user clicks on column?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i understand what you want. You can fire column event from the grid eventHandler like this:

```
grid.addListener(Events.CellClick, new Listener<GridEvent<ModelData>>() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(@NotNull GridEvent<ModelData> ge) {
     ge.getGrid().getColumnModel().getColumn(ge.getColIndex()).fireEvent(Events.ColumnClick);
  }
});
```

Then before adding column to your grid ColumnModel you should add Listener on it:

```
final ColumnConfig column = new ColumnConfig();
column.addListener(Events.ColumnClick, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(@NotNull BaseEvent be) {
    GWT.log("I was clicked!!!");
  }
});
```

I don't know is there better way to do it.

Comment: ye, thank you, i did same code. Its works only for Grid. But I need to fire different event when clicking on 1st column, an when clicking on other columns of grid.